# Mouse over click response on image in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I want to know what plugins is used on to chanege the color of image or make image response on mouse over.

I am new in wordpress can anyone give me the list of best plugins.

I am editing this theme:

```
http://themeforest.net/item/overgrowth-retina-responsive-multipurpose-theme/full_screen_preview/4896083
```

Please check this theme, in Homepage Scrolldown the page the "BLOG" Section will come

Please put mouse over the image then image will response.

I am looking for this.

I purchased this theme and I am editing it but I am not able to do this feature.

And I do not know this name what it says so I am not able to search on internet.

So please tell me what I will search what this say in WordPress. How can it be achieved via code or via plugins?

Does my overgrowth retina theme have this plugins?

Any Idea or Suggestions would be highly welcome.

Answer (score 0):

This effect is being achieved with CSS3:

1] It's setting `border-radius:100%;` of the image container to change the image from a square to a circle.

2] It's also displaying two hidden elements over top of the image for the blue semi-transparent overlay. These are being set to `opacity:0;` for their default state, and then on `:hover`, they are being displayed using CSS `transition`.

3] They are using CSS3 transitions and trandsforms to deliver a smooth animation rather than the CSS styles just snapping into their `:hover` state.

Image Container :hover CSS:

```
.blog.blog_layout5 .span3 .post_grid_image a:hover > img, .blogging.post_grid .column.span3:hover .data-image > img, .blogging.post_grid .span3.four_column:hover .data-image > img {
    border-radius: 100%;
    transform: scale(1.08, 1.08);
}
```

Semi-Transparent Blue Circle Overlay :hover CSS:

```
.blogging.post_grid .span3 .preview_info_wrap, .blog.blog_layout5 .preview_info_wrap {
    border-radius: 100%;
    transform: scale(1.08, 1.08);
    transition: opacity 0.2s ease 0s;
}
```

Icon Container Overlay (The Icon on top of the Blue Overlay) :hover CSS:

```
.blogging.post_grid .span3 .preview_info_wrap, .blog.blog_layout5 .preview_info_wrap {
    border-radius: 100%;
    transform: scale(1.08, 1.08);
    transition: opacity 0.2s ease 0s;
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for you reply. But I want to know where to put these lines of code? How to use this code? I am beginner and I am not reaching here on CSS3. Please suggest me what I do and where put these lines of code.